# Azure Notification Hub not working on webform and MVC but works on ConsoleApplication

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

when i use this code in webform or MVC system keep hangs and stay in this line of code :

```
 AppleRegistrationDescription vb = 
await hubClient.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(token, new string[] { tag });
```

but in Console works fine

this is my code

```
static async Task<AppleRegistrationDescription> appleregister(string tag, string token)
        {
            var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://ipluzservicehub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=o9DAUFuT1n9AyHfuc8REkwo0W/65WAw1SSG+fNJ/xqg=", "taylors");
            AppleRegistrationDescription vb = await hubClient.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(token, new string[] { tag });
            return vb;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                Task<AppleRegistrationDescription> t = appleregister("MYTag", "19606e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                var list = t.Result;
                var id = list.RegistrationId;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return View();
        }
```

can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of failure are you experiencing?
Sometimes the async context in ASP.NET app could be the culprit, which causes the async call to hang.
Try to use:

```
 AppleRegistrationDescription vb = await hubClient.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(token, new string[] { tag }).configureAwait(false);
```

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks Elio by Adding .configureAwait(false); Problem has been solved and now working

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you're using ASP.NET 4.5, and that you have set the `httpRuntime.targetFramework` element in your web.config to `4.5`.

Also, you shouldn't use `Result` in ASP.NET (or WinForms); [you can easily cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  try
  {
    Task<AppleRegistrationDescription> t = appleregister("MYTag", "19606e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var list = await t;
    var id = list.RegistrationId;
  }
  catch
  {
  }
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen , your post gave me good idea, and i learned a lot ,but for this case adding .configureAwait(false); (Elio's post) solved my problem 
thanks

Comment: It fixed the hang, but that solution will hurt your scalability.